# What does Eren mean by 誰かを？

Tags: translation, particle-を, anime

Watching [the preview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jRVKBrJ7X-o) for the second part of the 4th Attack on Titan season, Eren can be heard saying:

> 待っていたんだろう,ずっと [I've been waiting it seems, throughout]
>
> 二千年前から [since 2,000 years ago]
>
> 誰かを [who's there? someone? who are you? who does that?]

Here's the [ichi.moe translation](https://ichi.moe/cl/qr/?q=%E5%BE%85%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86%2C%E3%81%9A%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8%2C%E4%BA%8C%E5%8D%83%E5%B9%B4%E5%89%8D%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%2C+%E8%AA%B0%E3%81%8B%E3%82%92&r=htr).

I hope I got most of the translation right. But I'm confused - what is implied by the 誰かを?

Comment: Isn't it just the object paired with 待つ? It's also "someone" and not "who." (I cannot watch the video now to see it more in context).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does Eren mean by 誰かを？

It means **"(for) someone"**.

> I hope I got most of the translation right.

Almost right! Good try but a bit off here and there.

---

Firstly, you translated as 待っていたんだろう. It should be 待っていたんだろ.
The former can be translated into an assumption "(it) must have been waiting".
The latter can be translated into a rhetorical-ish question "(you) were waiting, weren't you?"

**Translation should be:**

待っていたんだろ,ずっと [Been waiting haven't you, throughout]

二千年前から [since 2,000 years ago]

誰かを [for someone]

In plain simple English:
**"(You've) been waiting, haven't you, for someone this whole time, since 2,000 years ago".**

Words came out in following order:
**"(You've) been waiting, haven't you, this whole time, since 2,000 years ago, for someone".**

Words are shuffled but doesn't change the meaning of sentence/phrase.
Such shuffling (倒置法) might have made it hard to translate, [but you're not alone.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E5%80%92%E7%BD%AE%E6%B3%95)